# Is there a way to retrieve active subscriptions or the purchase history for a user and only to a specific Android app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-docs-api, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I would like to know if there is an API or endpoint that I can call/use to retrieve active subscriptions or the purchase history for a user and only to a specific app. To explain what I want to achieve, I am going to tell you what I currently have developed:

- An Android app that has an active subscription that users can subscribe to.
- Once a user pays and Google Play calls onPurchasesUpdated(), to deliver the result of the purchase operation, the app handles the purchase.
- To handle the purchase, the app sends the sku, purchaseToken and other relevant information to our server.
- As soon as the server returns a 200 OK to the app HTTPS POST request, the app acknowledges that subscription based on the purchaseToken.
- If a user wants to check their active subscriptions that information is available through the following url: https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions
- If a user wants to check their purchase history that information is available through the following url: https://play.google.com/store/account/orderhistory

So based on this information, I would like to know how can I obtain information about all the purchases (or the last one), either with the Google Play Billing Library or the Google Play Developer API (or other), so that I can access the purchaseToken information. My objective is to have a way to access, from within the app, a list of that user's subscriptions or just it's last purchaseToken. Note that I do not want to get access to a list that includes other apps purchases or history. Only the info about my app.